# LP for gas stove

Tags: propane, stove-top

I am trying to hook up a 40# LP tank to my house to supply my gas stove.  I have the LP conversion kit installed and piping installed and inspected to the the exterior.  Can I just use flexible piping (i.e. Mr Heater type/gas grill) and connect it from the house termination to the tank?

Comment: I haven't read through the codes, but I think either rigid pipe (black steel pipe), or [Corrugated stainless steel tubing (CSST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrugated_stainless_steel_tubing) is acceptable.  You're probably not going to be using the same piping you used for your portable gas grill, unless your gas grill is really heavy duty.

Answer (score 1):

The gas grill lines aren't OK but CSST, which is a flexible line usually painted yellow for interior or black plastic coating for exterior, should be OK. Here is a safety website about CSST http://www.csstsafety.com/